# Ubuntu 18.04.1 Lagging mouse and login issues

Tags: nvidia, graphics, login, mouse

I recently wanted to try out Ubuntu again as I havent used it since 14.04 and have always had fun using it.
I installed it on my laptop which is running an Intel CPU, nVidia graphics and 16GB of RAM.

Upon first boot and many to go, the mouse at login would always lag and typing in my password to login would skip or place additional characters, possibly reading the keyboard input additional times upon key press?
Typing slowly allowed myself to login, at first it would be a blank black screen, then load the mouse, finally it would redirect me back to the login. 
Restarting and attempting to login yielded a small success rate in which a random reboot would cause no mouse problems and login was a success.

I had also ttyd into a session to update the computer while login was persisting to fail.

Notes
1. No error message occurs on the gui but I havent checked any log files inside var or xsession (Does this exist as a file in home on Ubuntu?)
2. I had ran update, upgrade and dist upgrade all while this problem still persists.

Anyways thanks all, hopefully a resolution can occur.

Comment: Just saying, mint is better, check out your irq interrupts and see was spiking, irqs interrupts are like a kid saying, mom, mom, mom, mom, mom, mom, hang on hunny, OK what. Mom, mom, mom, mom what hunny :)

Comment: Seems the CPU is overwhelmed, do you have irqbalance installed so it can distribute the irqs across your cpus , top is your friend here